# Why are my predicted values all nearly identical (and similar to the mean)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, time-series, linear-regression

I've removed the trend and seasonality from a dataset containing 911 fire calls for a particular city, recorded hourly, over 17 years.  I've then fit it with a linear regressor, and attempted to predict the values for the forthcoming 24-hour period.  However, my R^2 value is typically near 0 (often negative), and my predicted values are all within one 10,000th (or less) of each other, so when plotted, it essentially looks like a horizontal line roughly reflecting the mean value.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
from datetime import timedelta
def run_regression(df, dependent, label):
    cut_datetime = df[dependent].max()-timedelta(hours=26) #24 hour lag plus 4 hours to predict

    train = df[df[dependent] < cut_datetime][['julian_datetime', label]].dropna(how='any') #train == data before cut_datetime
    test = df[df[dependent] >= cut_datetime][['julian_datetime', label]].dropna(how='any') #test == data after cut_datetime

    regress = sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression().fit(
                                              X = train[['julian_datetime']],
                                              y = train[label])

    test['predicted_value'] = regress.predict(
                                              X = test[['julian_datetime']])

    #Plots
    (test[label] - test['predicted_value']).plot()
    test[[label, 'predicted_value']].plot()

    #Metrics
    print('MSE: ', sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error(test[label], test['predicted_value']))
    print('R^2: ', sklearn.metrics.r2_score(test[label], test['predicted_value']))
    print('Sample of predicted values: ', '\n', test['predicted_value'][:10])

run_regression(exp_model_df, 'incident_hour', 'label')
```

`incident_hour` --> the datetime format of `julian_date` referenced at the beginning of the function

Here's a sample of the dataset:

```
incident_hour   julian_datetime     label
0   2003-11-07 09:00:00     2452950.87500000    6.696136
1   2003-11-07 10:00:00     2452950.91666667    -5.293884
2   2003-11-07 11:00:00     2452950.95833333    5.679681
3   2003-11-07 12:00:00     2452951.00000000    4.411278
4   2003-11-07 13:00:00     2452951.04166667    5.837476
5   2003-11-07 14:00:00     2452951.08333333    6.469543
6   2003-11-07 15:00:00     2452951.12500000    2.191286
7   2003-11-07 16:00:00     2452951.16666667    0.347877
8   2003-11-07 17:00:00     2452951.20833333    0.151539
9   2003-11-07 18:00:00     2452951.25000000    5.925230
10  2003-11-07 19:00:00     2452951.29166667    8.563340
11  2003-11-07 20:00:00     2452951.33333333    3.151843
12  2003-11-07 21:00:00     2452951.37500000    3.751080
13  2003-11-07 22:00:00     2452951.41666667    5.476664
14  2003-11-07 23:00:00     2452951.45833333    0.146253
15  2003-11-08 00:00:00     2452951.50000000    2.879449
16  2003-11-08 01:00:00     2452951.54166667    0.712886
17  2003-11-08 02:00:00     2452951.58333333    6.118765
18  2003-11-08 03:00:00     2452951.62500000    6.052857
19  2003-11-08 04:00:00     2452951.66666667    0.892937
20  2003-11-08 05:00:00     2452951.70833333    -3.009876
21  2003-11-08 06:00:00     2452951.75000000    -3.525916
22  2003-11-08 07:00:00     2452951.79166667    -0.076345
23  2003-11-08 08:00:00     2452951.83333333    -3.236072
24  2003-11-08 09:00:00     2452951.87500000    -2.855910
25  2003-11-08 10:00:00     2452951.91666667    3.599330
26  2003-11-08 11:00:00     2452951.95833333    6.845144
27  2003-11-08 12:00:00     2452952.00000000    6.764351
28  2003-11-08 13:00:00     2452952.04166667    -1.896929
29  2003-11-08 14:00:00     2452952.08333333    0.370614
30  2003-11-08 15:00:00     2452952.12500000    4.899800
31  2003-11-08 16:00:00     2452952.16666667    7.245627
32  2003-11-08 17:00:00     2452952.20833333    1.559531
33  2003-11-08 18:00:00     2452952.25000000    8.437391
34  2003-11-08 19:00:00     2452952.29166667    4.957201
35  2003-11-08 20:00:00     2452952.33333333    1.349833
36  2003-11-08 21:00:00     2452952.37500000    6.257467
37  2003-11-08 22:00:00     2452952.41666667    -1.221531
38  2003-11-08 23:00:00     2452952.45833333    0.552749
39  2003-11-09 00:00:00     2452952.50000000    -0.917920
40  2003-11-09 01:00:00     2452952.54166667    -4.394944
41  2003-11-09 02:00:00     2452952.58333333    -2.238189
42  2003-11-09 03:00:00     2452952.62500000    -1.062656
43  2003-11-09 04:00:00     2452952.66666667    3.813087
44  2003-11-09 05:00:00     2452952.70833333    -4.540094
45  2003-11-09 06:00:00     2452952.75000000    2.680210
46  2003-11-09 07:00:00     2452952.79166667    4.581881
47  2003-11-09 08:00:00     2452952.83333333    3.803750
48  2003-11-09 09:00:00     2452952.87500000    6.590574
49  2003-11-09 10:00:00     2452952.91666667    8.227202
```

Here's a plot of the results:

[image]

Comment: Is it time series data ? I think you will need to train a sequence model for it.

Comment: @mohsinali - it is time series data.  As mentioned above, trend and seasonality have been removed. What do you mean by "sequence model".  And why would the model I've trained be insufficient?

Comment: Sorry it must have skipped my eyes while reading. To the best of my knowledge this kind of data is hard to learn by simple liner regression models. Because the data has peaks that simple line could not be fitted to it. These sort of problems are then dealt with deep learning (RNNs/LSTMs). I think you should look into this https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-forecasting-long-short-term-memory-network-python/  . This is sort of a similar problem.

Comment: I'll look into using a different model, but I'm not sure I agree.  I have another model that I'm using as a template that models temperatures over time.  The data (with regards to its structure of rapid peaks and valleys) looks identical, and it's learning at an R^2 of 0.826.  I appreciate the tip though (especially since I plan on moving over to other models later), and will take a look at the LSTM article you linked.  Thanks!

Comment: What is the variance of your dependent variable? In your sample, the value of julian_datetime is always the same. Maybe there is a data prep issue...

Comment: @BMW, Good thought. Variance=14.008.  At the request of those below, I updated the format of the `julian_date` values above to show they're actually different from each other.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be certain unless you provide the test set that produced those predicted values.

Based on the code, you're fitting a model with a single independent variable `julian_datetime` to predict your dependent variable `label`. Based on your sample data, the `julian_datetime` variable has a very high amount of repeating values. I wouldn't be surprised if you had the same `julian_datetime` value for each observation in your test set. This would lead to the same prediction, since each input is the same.

If this is the case, and you're still not convinced, try moving a few observations from your training set to your test set with different `julian_datetime` values to see if you receive different predictions. You will most likely notice different predictions for those new observations. As a result, you will see changes in your line.

**Update**

I believe there are a few reasons why the line is unchanged:

1. I believe your training set includes around 140000 observations in total, and your test set includes 25-100 observations. Also, your plot only includes data about the test set. Therefore, your predictions will seem to be unchanged, since you're plotting a linear regression line on a very small window.
2. Your linear regression line be fairly flat again if time has no effect on your response at all.

If you still want to go forward with building a linear regression model, I would recommend doing the following:

- Make sure your test set is large enough to notice changes in the predictions, or you will run into this same problem.
- Try including sin and cos functions in your model in an attempt to account for possible seasonality

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts.  I took a look at the `julian_datetime` values, and they're actually all unique (max value of `julian_datetime.value_counts(ascending=False)` is `1`).  They're just formatted in such a way above that many appear identical.  That being said, as my predicted values are not very far apart (as I mentioned in my original question), I suspect that maybe it is a problem with, at least, the format of the julian_datetime column.  A datetime format won't work with the linear regression though (to my knowledge), so any other ideas for an alternative format is welcome.

Comment: Could you update your question with the actual julian_datetime values? It would be even better if you could provide the actual julian_datetime values that produced your plot.

Comment: Yes, I think that's a good idea.  Those above have been updated.  This is for the first 50 (of something like 140000).

Comment: After seeing the updated data, you are right to say the values are nearly identical, which is definitely causing the issue. Since each input is almost identical, you'll receive an almost identical output. Other than formatting the variable as a categorical variable, the only other thing you could do is scale your variables: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29781/when-conducting-multiple-regression-when-should-you-center-your-predictor-varia

Comment: At this point, I believe your question has been answered of **why** are my predictions the same. If you would like to get into a new discussion about **how** to resolve this issue, then I think it may be best to ask a new question with more specific specifications

Comment: Presumably, an accurate understanding of the **why** would produce a solution (the **how**), no?  I just scaled the `juilan_datetime` variable, as suggested with no new development.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206878/discussion-between-dkhara-and-alofgran).

Answer (score 0):

You are using the complete wrong approach for time series.

Lets have a look what is Linear Regression doing:

```
julian_datetime     label
0   2.452951e+06    6.696136
1   2.452951e+06    -5.293884
2   2.452951e+06    5.679681
3   2.452951e+06    4.411278
4   2.452951e+06    5.837476
```

So basically he will find funcion to  `f(x) = a*x +b` and your `x= julian_datetime` and `f(x)= label`. And he will minize the loss from `label-prediction`, so the problem is to all the numbers `2.45,...,2.45` he will find another number. But in timeseries you have to work with a flow of the data! Right now there is no time included at all.

One example to make it to a timeseries (which is not the best approach) is to add all the previous 2 values as a feature to it, so that it looks like:

```
julian_datetime     julian_datetime-1 julian_datetime-2 label
0   2.452951e+06                                         6.696136
1   2.452951e+06    2.452951e+06                         -5.293884
2   2.452951e+06    2.452951e+06     2.452951e+06       5.679681
3   2.452951e+06    2.452951e+06     2.452951e+06       4.411278
```

btw why is julian datetime always the same value? Ah it is even worse! You have to use the label column as previous value so that it looks like:

```
   y          y-1        y-2
0 6.696136
1 -5.293884  6.696136
2 5.679681   -5.293884           6.696136
3
```

then your trianing is `y-1, y-2` and your prediction `y`

Comment: You said that "Right now, there is no time included at all", however, `julian_datetime` is a representation of exactly that, albeit not in the traditional format (but nonetheless, it should be considered a time series)...Help me if I'm misunderstanding your statement.

Comment: As to your question about the `julian_datetime` values, they're actually not all the same (in fact, each are unique).  The format above (a mistake on my part) would make one think they are identical  only because they don't display enough decimal places to represent individual values.  As I mentioned in the comments to the answer above though, I did double check the values and can confirm they're all unique (as one would expect in a time series).  To your last point, I did lag my label column by 24 hours (`exp_model_df['label'] = exp_model_df['noise'].shift(-24)`).

Comment: I've updated the format of the `julian_datetime` values in the original question.

Comment: then the first comment is correct, forget the part with julian datetime...

Comment: help me understand what you mean...what is the first comment?  And if by the 'first comment' you mean that 'no time is included', then can you help me understand why `julian_datetime` does not count as a format of time included in the model.